# Find mismatch in boost match results

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm using boost::regex_match and I'm trying to find a function to obtain the position where the regular expression stopped matching. I couldn't find any attribute in the boost::match_results object, but several code snippets in which boost::regex_search is used to show the submatches. Am I on the right path with my implementation or do I've to do something different in order to achieve that? My code looks as follows:

```
int main(int args, char** argv)
{
    boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> what;

    if(args == 3) 
    {
        std::string text(argv[1]);
        boost::regex expression(argv[2]);

        std::cout << "Text : " << text << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Regex: " << expression << std::endl;

        if(boost::regex_match(text, what, expression, boost::match_default) != 0) 
        {
            int i = 0;

            for(boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator>::const_iterator it=what.begin(); it!=what.end(); ++it) 
            {
                std::cout << "[" << (i++) << "] " << it->str() << std::endl;
            }
            std::cout << "Matched!" << std::endl;
        } 
        else 
        {
            std::string::const_iterator start = text.begin();
            std::string::const_iterator end   = text.end();

            while(boost::regex_search(start, end, what, expression)) 
            {
                std::string submatch(what[1].first, what[1].second);
                std::cout << submatch << std::endl;
                start = what[0].second;
            }
            std::cout << "Didn't match!" << std::endl;
        }
    } //if(args == 3)
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid usage! $> ./boost-regex <text> <regex>" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$> ./boost_regex "We're building it up to burn it down" ".*(build.*)(to.*)(burn.*)"
Text : We're building it up to burn it down
Regex: .*(build.*)(to.*)(burn.*)
[0] We're building it up to burn it down
[1] building it up
[2] to
[3] burn it down
Matched!

$> ./boost_regex "We're building it up to burm it down" ".*(build.*)(to.*)(burn.*)"
Text : We're building it up to burm it down
Regex: .*(build.*)(to.*)(burn.*)
Didn't match!
```

For the last input I'd like to have the something similar to:

```
Text : We're building it up to burm it down
Regex: .*(build.*)(to.*)(burn.*)
[0] We're building it up to
[1] building it up
[2] to
Didn't match!
```

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, you have a problem with the regex in your example.  Because it can't match the `(burn.*)` subgroup, the entire regex fails to match anything, and returns no results.  Adding a "?" after `(burn.*)` would make it so the first two subgroups would match, and the third would not.

I would checkout rubular.com, it's a great tool for tweaking your regular expressions and watching them work in realtime.

To test if a subgroup did or did not participate in a match, you need to check the `sub_match::matched` boolean variable in your for loop, it will be true if the subgroup matched.  check the documentation for boost::submatch [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/sub_match.html)

Hope this helped, it's actually my first Stackoverflow post, answer, or comment. :)

Comment: You're right with the regular expression, I saw it with regextester.com and with my application too! Do you've a suggestion for a regular expression which could achieve the behavior described above? I tried it but I couldn't find any =( The objective is to see which part has matched and which didn't! Exactly like it's determined with boost::spirit::parse_info::stop.

Comment: OK, I've found a suitable regular expression for my application area. You already mentioned it with the "?", but I didn't come up with the correct regexp. It looks as follows (feel free to respond for improvements): (We)?('re)?[\s\n]{0,}(building)?[\s\n]{0,}(it)?[\s\n]{0,}(up)?[\s\n]{0,}(to)?[\s\n]{0,}(burn)?[\s\n]{0,}(it)?[\s\n]{0,}(down)?[\s\n]{0,}

Comment: @janr I could be wrong, but I think you can save yourself a little pain by using "*" instead of "{0,}" and by using just "\s" instead of "\s\n".  They mean the same thing, respectively.  So you could do this instead : `(We)?('re)?[\s]*(building)?[\s](it)?[\s]*(up)?[\s]*(to)?[\s‌​]*(burn)?[\s]*(it)?[\s]*(down)?[\s]*`.